# How to return a generic delegate to curry type parameters?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

In C# if I want to curry concrete types I could write something like this:

```
Func<int, string> CurryFirstInt(int value) => otherValue => (value + otherValue).toString();
```

Additionally I could also use a generic on the outer function, to store some details about that first type parameter, e.g.:

```
interface ISample {
    int Value { get; }
}

Func<int, string> CurryTypeParam<T>(T sample) where T : ISample
    => otherValue => $"{typeof(T).Name}: {sample.value + otherValue}"
```

Now what I'd like is to have the returned delegate be generic as well, but with a different type parameter, so we can capture two different type parameters in two steps without having to resort to reflection. Essentially I'm looking for something like this:

```
delegate string Foo<T>();

Foo CreateFoo<T>()
{
    string FooImp<U>() => $"{typeof(T).Name} / {typeof(U).Name}";
    return FooImp;
}

var foo = CreateFoo<int>();
foo<double>(); // -> "Int32 / Double"
foo<string>(); // -> "Int32 / String"
```

The motivation for this is currying parts of type parameters when registering generic services using `IServiceCollection`, e.g.

```
interface IFoo<T, U> { }

class Foo<T, U> : IFoo<T, U> { }

delegate IServiceCollection RegisterFoo<T>();

RegisterFoo CreateRegistration<T>(IServiceCollection services)
{
    void Register<U>() => services.AddSingleton<IFoo<T, U>, Foo<T, U>>;

    return Register;
}

var services = new ServiceCollection();
var register = CreateRegistration<int>(services);
register<string>(); // registers singleton IFoo<int, string> with implementation Foo<int, string>
```

Comment: When you're using the term "curry" you're actually demonstrating closing over a value.  Currying is something different than what you're doing.

Comment: Is it? I was sure currying was decomposing a function such as `f(x, y) -> result` into `g(x) -> h(y) -> result` of which closing over a value would be one example of the general purpose definition.

Comment: None of the instances of you using the term "currying" in the question involve turning a delegate of two arguments into a delegate of one argument whose result is a delegate of one argument that, when called, performs the original delegate using the two provided arguments.  Your question only involves a method that takes a value and returns a delegate that uses that value, which involves closing over that parameter.